# Using Certification Test Tool for Windows Server 2016/9

Tags: c#, windows, windows-server-2016, app-certification-kit

Unlike the test tool for Windows 10, which is part of the Windows 10 SDK, Microsoft went out of their way to make the certification tool for Windows Server 2016 complicated.

[image: Convoluted and Bug-Ridden Microsoft Certification Test Preview Tool for Windows Server 2016]

I installed my test application and specified the path to the Inno Setup installer, off the Downloads folder, and specified the location of the binary files, namely the Program Files location, and the screen shown, I specified the process name, basically the executable file name. At least System Internal's Process Monitor utility said that was the name.

As you can see, I got thrown an error.

```
Log Time: 12/04/2018 08:57:21
MethodName:: ApplicationRunningViewModel.VerifyApplication
Message: 
No running application's process found after your application installation.

==================================================================
Log Time: 12/04/2018 08:57:58
MethodName:: ApplicationRunningViewModel.VerifyAppProcess
Message: 
Process not found in snapshot file.

==================================================================
```

How do I resolve the error? Basically, how is the steps to use this test tool?

**Background:**
I had previously certified my application for Windows 10 in the Windows Platform Ready / Winqual area of Microsoft and obtained the Microsoft Gold Application Development competency.

I was expecting to simply pay the yearly extortion fee, $5400, when I logged into the portal, saw the new redesigned Partner Center, and went to the Competency Summary section, where I saw the message that I am in danger to lose the competency. Microsoft apparently did away application certification based competencies for Application Development. Talking to MS external support, I was told what I already saw on my own that the Silver ISV is the only path forward testing against Windows Server 2016. My attempts to talk to a real Microsoft employee or find a real solution failed miserably. I think talking to Google is easier. I hope that MS straightens things out for next year. By the way, the Platform Ready / WinQual area disappeared as well as all certifications.

That brings me to my question. I am trying to use the Windows Server 2016 test tool (2019 was not available last week for download, hence 2016).

I already installed the application. It works fine on Windows Server 2016, just Microsoft did not make application verification easy.

How do I resolve this error? What piece of information does it want and how do I obtain it?

Comment: I tried the test again today and to my surprise I was able to go all the way to the end. I had signing problems and other issues, but upon rerun, the same thing. I keep trying different things, but nothing, just `process not found in snapshot file`, but no location of this snapshot file. Same problem. It appears this problem is intermittent, which means a bug in the test tool is my guess.

Comment: The tool is intermittent and after many, many attempts I was able to obtain the test results, HOWEVER all was for naught. I just noticed this sentence on MPN `The core benefits outlined here are not applicable to the ISV Silver or Gold competency.` The idiots at MS did not seem to care about this clause. ISV comes with no software benefits. As such, useless. That means there is for the time being no application based way to obtain a MS Competency, which includes software benefits. The only way is to have 2/4 employees with certs. Total b.s.

Comment: I think this might have now been revised to: "If you attained a Silver or Gold ISV competency on or after November 8, 2018 and this is your only competency, you are not eligible for core benefits; however, you can still use your current ISV competency benefits until your anniversary date." according to [partner.microsoft.com](https://partner.microsoft.com/en-gb/membership/core-benefits)

Answer (score 1):

I found the same error while testing my application using the **Certification Test Tool 1.0 for Windows Server** for Windows Server 2019.
I just changed the sequence of the test. I did launch the tool and then installed my application. If you cancel the test your application must be reinstalled in order for the test tool to recognize your process. Everything worked as expected

I got another error while using the **Certification Test Tool Preview for Windows Server 2016**. He couldn't validate my signed assemblies because the tool verify the aseemblies signature usign the signtool.exe instead of sn.exe. If you signed your assemblies using the sn.exe, neither of the test tools for Windows server 2016 & 2019 will validate your signed assemblies. I had to check the log file generated by the test tool and sign the assemblies manually using the signtool.exe.

I hope this information help someone havign the same issues.
Greetings

Comment: As mentioned above you must install while the application is running. In my case this was just copying files onto the server, but it had to happen while the tool was on the install screen. After that everything worked as expected.